# Возврат во Fragment из нового Activity при нажатии Back в Toolbar

Tags: android, android-fragment, toolbar, drawerlayout

Есть MainActivity с DrawerLayout (создано стандартными средствами AndroidStudio по шаблону), при выборе любого из пунктов DrawerLayout создается и реплейсится в контейнере Fragment, в котором можно запустить новое Activity (к примеру для подробной информации по позиции). Затем пользователь нажимает кнопку Back в Toolbar и попадает не в тот фрагмент, откуда он пришел во второе активити, а на главную страницу. При нажатии на кнопку назад на телефоне все норм. Я пытался обработать в OnMenuItemSelected нажатие и реализовать onBackPressed, но не помогло.
Отсюда вопрос - как поступить, что бы при нажатии кнопки назад в тулбаре происходило то же действие, что и при нажатии на кнопку назад на телефоне?

ПС: В логах вижу, что фрагмент не уничтожается до того момента, как пользователь не нажмет кнопку назад в тулбаре, такое ощущение, что вообще все приложение перезапускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте для нового Activity необходимо **убрать** параметр

```
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
```

В Activity необходимо обработать клик по кнопке "Назад"

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        finish();
    }
}
```